# How is 'role does not exist' error possible, when the role actually exists

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

how is this error possible after migrate command :

```
      File "/Users/TheKotik/tick-tock/denv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "TheKotik" does not exist
```

if the role is actually created and has all right on that?

At psql everything is correct

```
grant all privileges on database tick to TheKotik;
GRANT
```

Comment: Did you commit after the create/grant? What do you see if, from the psql prompt, you type `\du thekotik`? Same question for `\du "TheKotik"`.

Comment: Make sure your connection string points to the correct database (and possibly schema if you're using one).

Answer (score 1):

if `grant all privileges on database tick to TheKotik;` gives no error, your username is thekotik, not the TheKotik.

Change "TheKotik" to "thekotik" in python connects string config, or create an appropriate user:

```
create user "TheKotik";
grant all privileges on database tick to "TheKotik";
```

Comment: in fact I tried changing user to default postgres and it worked, but then it caused the sam error with database, claiming it doesn't exist(here all lowercase) . it worked only with default postgres database with role postgres

Comment: Sorry - I grounded my answer based on what information you provided in question